# best way to store data in Java like pickle

Tags: java, json, xml, file, serialization

Basically, I just want to save two integeres into a File, so that i can reuse them the next time the programm starts. Id like to do it like pickle in python, beacuse writing it just into a txt file is cumbersome. I have read some articles and other questions wehere they say I should use Java serializatio or XML or JSON, but Im not sure wheter that is the right thing in my case. Id like to use the easiest way. 
thank you very much in advance for trying to solve my problem! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use serialization, XML or JSON (usually with additional libraties). An easy way to store configuration data in files is by using Java property files which are supported by the JRE without any additional dependencies. Property files are text files and have a simple `key=value` syntax, see below. To write two values to a property file you can do

```
  String prop1 = "foo";
  String prop2 = "bar";

  try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties")) {

      Properties prop = new Properties();

      // set the properties value
      prop.setProperty("prop1", prop1);
      prop.setProperty("prop2", prop2);

      // save properties to project root folder
      prop.store(output, "my app's config file");
  } catch (IOException io) {
      io.printStackTrace();
      // TODO: improve error handling
  }
```

which should give you something like

```
#my app's config file
#Sat Feb 29 12:29:27 CET 2020
prop2=bar
prop1=foo
```

And to load it:

```
try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("config.properties")) {

Properties prop = new Properties();

// load a properties file
prop.load(input);

// get the property value and print it out
String prop1 = prop.getProperty("prop1");
String prop2 = prop.getProperty("prop2");

System.out.println("prop1 = " + prop1);
System.out.println("prop2 = " + prop2);

} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
  // TODO: improve error handling
}
```

For integer values you would need some type conversion, e.g. the first two lines would be

```
String prop1 = Integer.toString(23);
String prop2 = Integer.toString(42);
```

and reading the properties then becomes

```
int prop1 = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("prop1"));
int prop2 = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("prop2"));
```

This solution does not scale well in case the number of properties increases or there are frequent changes. For a more generic procedure, see this post: [Get int, float, boolean and string from Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723839/get-int-float-boolean-and-string-from-properties)

Comment: thank you very much, it works, but Im not sure beacause, in my case the user shouldnt be able to change the values and isnt that the case with .property files?

Comment: @JGStyleSSBU: You asked for a solution to keep the number between two runs of the software, and your idea was to store them in a file on disk. ANY file on disk can be modified by the user as long as you do not take several precautions by applying access rights and stuff … no matter if the file is a properties file or something else. To keep the values away from the user, setup a service (like a database or Zookeeper or something else) where to store the numbers … but I think that is far to big for your requirements. Perhaps you would like to take a look to the Preferences API in Java?

Comment: I just changier the James of the variables to Dome Numbers so Theo the User Dozent know what hes doing

Comment: And the alles i Save multiplied hey a Hit number